# Is Compact Language Detector 2's detect method thread safe?

Tags: java, c++, thread-safety, jna

We are using the Java Wrapper implementation of [Compact Language Detector 2](https://github.com/commoncrawl/language-detection-cld2).

Is [the detect() function](https://github.com/commoncrawl/language-detection-cld2/blob/f48d7c0a6a9b9de4ea91315ef4405f99f0e2c69f/src/main/java/org/commoncrawl/langdetect/cld2/Cld2.java#L127) thread-safe?

From what I understand, it invokes [this library function](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2/blob/b56fa78a2fe44ac2851bae5bf4f4693a0644da7b/internal/compact_lang_det_impl.cc#L1707).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not thread safe if the native code was compiled with `CLD2_DYNAMIC_MODE` set, which you could test using the function `isDataDynamic()`.

The native function manipulates the static class variable `kScoringtables`.  If `CLD2_DYNAMIC_MODE` is defined at compilation, this variable is initialized to a set of null tables (`NULL_TABLES`) and can later be loaded with dynamic data, or unloaded, potentially by other threads.

It would be possible for the `kScoringtables.quadgram_obj` to be non-null [at the line 1762 null check](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2/blob/b56fa78a2fe44ac2851bae5bf4f4693a0644da7b/internal/compact_lang_det_impl.cc#L1762) and then the `kScoringtables` address altered before it is added to the cross-thread `ScoringContext` object on line 1777.  In this case, the wrong pointer would be passed to `ApplyHints` on line 1785, potentially causing bad things to happen at line 1606.

This would be a very rare race condition, but possible nonetheless, and is not thread safe for the same reason the standard "lazy getter" is not thread safe.

To make this thread-safe, you would have to either test that `isDataDynamic()` returns false, or ensure the `loadDataFromFile`, `loadDataFromRawAddress`, and `unloadData` functions could not be called by a different thread while you are executing this method (or at least until you are past line 1777...)